How to test null values with Zod validation in TypeScript without type errors?
This is my first time using Zod and I need help testing for null values in my schema validation.
I’m using Zod for validation and have set up a schema and endpoint like this:
app.post(
    '/api/users',
    validateRequest({ 
        body: z.object({
            username: z.string(),
            email: z.string(),
            password: z.string(),
        })
    }),
    async (req, res) => {
        const hashedPassword = await argon2.hash(req.body.password);
        await User.create({
            ...req.body,
            password: hashedPassword,
        });
        res.status(201).send({ message: 'User created' });
    },
);

The problem
I’m trying to write tests to check validation errors when username or other fields are null. Here’s a sample test:
it('should return a 400 status code when username is null', async () => {
    const response = await request(app)
        .post('/api/users')
        .send({
            username: null,
            email: 'user@admin.com',
            password: 'pass4User',
        });
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(400);
});

However, I’m getting this TypeScript error:
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

I can’t set username to null in the test without TypeScript complaining. What’s the best way to write tests to check if fields like username, email, etc., are null or invalid?
edit: I found the solution. I have added the answer.

I have just learned that there are several ways to achieve this, and I will rank them based on my preferences.
First, using the non-null assertion operator (!) at the end of an expression:
const response = await request(app)
    .post('/api/users')
    .send({
        username: null!,
        email: 'user@admin.com',
        password: 'pass4User',
    });
expect(response.statusCode).toBe(400);

Second, using casting with as:
const response = await request(app)
    .post('/api/users')
    .send({
        username: null as unknown as string,
        email: 'user@admin.com',
        password: 'pass4User',
    });
expect(response.statusCode).toBe(400);

Lastly, using // @ts-expect-error to mark the error as expected:
const response = await request(app)
    .post('/api/users')
    .send({
        // @ts-expect-error: Should expect string
        username: null,
        email: 'user@admin.com',
        password: 'pass4User',
    });
expect(response.statusCode).toBe(400);

